# Paste Value to Column X when Column A matches a value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with about 14 sheets. The first sheet, "Summary" has the following structure:

```
Electric Heat Comm. |    Month1    |    Month2    |    Month 3    |      etc.
NameA               | CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue |  CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue
NameB               | CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue |  CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue
NameC               | CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue |  CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue  
                    |     SUM      |      SUM     |     SUM       |      SUM 
BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ------ 
Gas Heat Comm.      |    Month1    |    Month2    |    Month 3    |      etc.
NameA               | CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue |  CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue
NameB               | CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue |  CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue
NameC               | CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue |  CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue  
                    |     SUM      |      SUM     |     SUM       |      SUM 
BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ------ 
Combo Heat Comm.    |    Month1    |    Month2    |    Month 3    |      etc.
NameA               | CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue |  CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue
NameB               | CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue |  CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue
NameC               | CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue |  CopiedValue  |  CopiedValue  
                    |     SUM      |      SUM     |     SUM       |      SUM 
BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ----- BLANK ROW ------ 
Total Est. Over     |  Total SUM   |   Total SUM  |   Total SUM   |   Total SUM
```

Each community has a dedicated worksheet in the workbook. That worksheet contains granular detail for each property in the community, but ONLY for the CURRENT month (old data is wiped at the end of each month.

The community specific worksheets are structured as follows:

```
Address | columns with other data & calculations | Estimated Overage ($) | Other data
123 Main| other data from other columns          | $XXX.XX               | Other data
122 Main| other data from other columns          | $XXX.XX               | Other data
Blank   | Blank                                  | SUM of above values   | blank
```

The `CopiedValue` in the "Summary" worksheet is the `SUM` of the "I" column in the community worksheet (Estimated Overage $). This value is already calculated by a formula at the bottom of the column each month within the Community specific worksheet (could be recalculated again if it makes the macro easier to write).

I am attempting to write a code that will check each cell in Column A of the "Summary" sheet for the community name (stored as text value each time the loop runs in a `STRING` called "db_community") and, when a match is found, insert the SUM of Column I in the first blank column to the right in the "Summary" worksheet. Essentially, matching the value to the appropriate community in Column A.

Here's the code I've written to start to try to accomplish this result:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim db_community As String

For Each cell In Worksheets("Summary").Range("A4:A24")
    If cell.Value = db_community Then
        'Paste value from cell in other sheet to first empty
        'cell at end of current row
    End If
Next cell
```

Each month, the cell containing the `SUM` in the individual sheets change (based on the number of entries that month). This is the code that writes the `SUM` of the column and stores it as a variable in the blank cell below the data:

```
Dim sumRow as Long
Dim overRow as Long
Dim overValue As Long

sumRow = Range("I4").End(xlDown).Row
Cells(sumRow + 1, "I").Formula = "=SUM(I4:I" & sumRow & ")"
overRow = Range("I4").End(xlDown).Row
overValue = Cells(overRow, "I").Value
```

So, essentially, in the "Summary" sheet I need to find in Column A when that cell's value equals  db_community (the community name) and paste the overValue to the appropriate cell in the new month's column. This then loops repeatedly until the entire worksheet is populated.

Most importantly, it needs to accommodate adding additional columns each month based on the new data and new calendar month.

If this still isn't clear, please ask. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There was a lot to take in here and it is kind of hard to understand the spreadsheet without actually seeing it since it is so large.  But after reading your question it sounds like `INDEX` and `MATCH` could be used instead of VBA, but that might get rather complicated.  VBA obviously still can work, you would just get the `Row` from the `cell` variable in your loop and just find the next empty cell in the proper sheet.  Just google `find empty cell in row` tons of results.

Comment: Finding the empty row works, except I have to find a new row based on the row of the matched value in Column A. That's the part I'm having problems with...  

Index Match would work, but I'd have to redo that each month when the new report ran. That's probably the short term fix until I figure out the code though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having read the updated original post, I believe this code suits your needs.

- This will examine the Value of Column "A" on "Summary"
- It will then look to each other sheet NOT named Summary, and check to see if the ws.Name matches the value from "A" on the row being examined.
- When it finds a match, it finds the last row of that Community sheet and creates a formula after the end of column "I".
- The value of the sum just created then gets sent back to the column AFTER the last column on the same row from Summary.
- Loop through every row on Summary and repeats that process.

**CODE:**

```
Sub MonthlyCommunityUpdte()

Dim source As String
Dim db_Community As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim tRow As Long        'set target row
Dim overValue As Double 'Not sure if you already declared this.
Dim lastCol As Long

    source = "Summary"
    lastRow = Sheets(source).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    lastCol = Sheets(source).Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For lRow = 2 To lastRow

            db_Community = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "A")

            For Each ws In Worksheets
                If ws.Name <> source Then           'Make sure not processing source again
                    If ws.Name = db_Community Then
                        tRow = Sheets(db_Community).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
                        Sheets(db_Community).Cells(tRow, "I").Formula = "=SUM(I4:I" & (tRow - 1) & ")"
                        overValue = Sheets(db_Community).Cells(tRow, "I")      'you can skip and
                                     'replace overValue in the next line with what it is = to.
                        Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, lastCol + 1) = overValue
                    End If
                End If

            Next ws
        Next lRow
End Sub
```

Comment: @johnwonderbread, I read your updated question.  Much easier to understand now, you clear the data every month in the Community sheet.  That explains why putting a sum in the bottom of "I" is no problem.  Have you tried the solution I posted?  I am pretty sure it does exactly what you want, except I'm using tempCommunity instead of db_community.  Updated with db_community

Comment: I'm getting a few errors, particularly on the "lCol = Sheets(source)..." row. 

Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error 

I've tried a few things, no luck. Thoughts?

Comment: @johnwonderbread, where is lCol?  DO you mean lastCol?  if so, are you naming your source = "Summary"?

Comment: PJ, I originally changed the naming convention of the variables you suggested. I've reverted back to your original naming methods. Above those two lines I have the line "source = "Summary"". The error persists.

Comment: OK.  I use lCol typically to represent LONG type Column number.  lastCol represents the lastColumn. Everyone has their variations.  Where is the error specifically?

Comment: The error appears on the following line: 
lastCol = Sheets(source).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlLeft).Column